# how to add usb storage device to qemu -M vexpress-a9 board

Tags: usb, qemu

I can startup kernel with qemu comand:

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -smp 1 -m 256 -kernel zImage -dtb vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb -drive file=rootfs.ext2,if=sd,format=raw -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0" -serial stdio -net nic,model=lan9118 -net user
```

but I cannot add a usb disk to the quem with the command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -smp 1 -m 256 -kernel zImage -dtb vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb -drive file=rootfs.ext2,if=sd,format=raw -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0" -serial stdio -net nic,model=lan9118 -net user -usb  -usbdevice disk:format=raw:sd.bin
audio: Could not init `oss' audio driver
qemu-system-arm: -usbdevice disk:format=raw:sd.bin: Error: no usb bus to attach usbdevice disk, please try -machine usb=on and check that the machine model supports USB
qemu: could not add USB device 'disk:format=raw:sd.bin'
```

how to add a usb disk to qemu vexpress-a9 board?